# Is there an easy command line command to check disk space?

Tags: command-line

"Command line" commands are very helpful. Is there a command to display the memory of each partition of my drives..?

Answer (score 77):

You can use `df` like so:

```
df -h
```

which will show something like this:

```
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/sda5        56G   47G  6.8G  88% /
none            4.0K     0  4.0K   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
udev            940M  4.0K  940M   1% /dev
tmpfs           192M  996K  191M   1% /run
none            5.0M     0  5.0M   0% /run/lock
none            957M  5.1M  952M   1% /run/shm
none            100M   44K  100M   1% /run/user
```

Comment: This method is commonly used to make sure there is enough disk space, as that is a common cause of MySQL errors:                                          
df -h
df -i

Comment: -h, --human-readable  print sizes in powers of 1024 (e.g., 1023M)

Answer (score 14):

Use the [`df`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/df) command:

```
df -h
```

to give you information about the various mounted filesystems on your computer, and their free and used space.